# Multiqueue tun/tap interface

Tags: tunneling, tc, tap, mqueue

I am trying to understand how Multiqueue tuntap interface works. Following the instructions provided at: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt
I was able to create multiple queues. However, I don't know how to check the queus status and where they are created. I tried:

```
$ tc -s class show dev tap0
```

(where tap0 is my tap interface), I see around 255 queues, even for a single ioctl call with IFF_MULTI_QUEUE flag. So probably I am looking at the wrong place. Here is the snippet of the output of the above command:

```
class mq :1 root
 Sent 4741 bytes 37 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
class mq :2 root
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
.
.
.
class mq :ff root
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
class mq :100 root
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

Secondly, I am not sure how to steer packets to these queues based on some filter or classifier using TC or anyother tool.

Comment: LARTC is your friend here - https://lartc.org/

Comment: Thanks @nwildner for the edits and suggestion. I have gone through LARTC, but couldn't find details about this particular case. I'll really appreciate if you can point me to any link that I might have missed.

Comment: For the second question, check my answer at: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/951385/multiqueue-tun-tap-interface/951769#951769